How to access and count section headers from a LangGraph state?
I'm working on a LangGraph project that will eventually generate reports automatically. I'm trying to count the total number of section headers, sub-section headers and sub-sub-section headers from the values in my "edited_outline" dictionary.
Below is the printed output of the current state. The dictionary key is "edited_outline" and the value is a long string of section, sub-section and sub-sub-section headers.
'edited_outline': 'Here is the refined report outline:\n'
                   '\n'
                   '**Section 1: Introduction to Management**\n'
                   '\n'
                   '1.1 Definition of Management and its significance in planning\n'
                   '1.1.1 Importance of Management in the landscape\n'
                   '1.2 Brief overview of the importance of Management for middle-aged working adults\n'
                   '\n'
                   '**Section 2: Types of Challenges Faced by Middle-Aged Working Adults**\n'
                   '\n'
                   '2.1 Housing challenges and their impact on stability\n'
                   '2.1.1 Case studies of middle-aged working adults struggling with housing payments\n'
                   '2.2 Credit challenges and their effects on credit scores\n'
                   '2.2.1 Statistics on credit challenges\n'
                   '2.3 Personal financial challenges and their implications on freedom\n'
                   '2.3.1 Examples of personal financial traps and how to avoid them\n'
                   '2.4 Business challenges and their risks for entrepreneurs\n'
                   '2.4.1 Case studies of entrepreneurs struggling with business financial issues\n'
                   '2.5 Tax challenges and their impact on planning\n'
                   '2.5.1 Importance of tax planning in Management\n'
                   '\n'

I have tried iterating through the value but have run into difficulties when filtering section headers from sub-section/sub-sub-section headers, due to their similar numbering.
